# PyQt4 on Mac: QGraphicsView with OpenGL is flickering

Tags: macos, opengl, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

under Mac OS X I have a problem with QGraphicsView and OpenGL. Sometimes, not everytime, when the QGraphicsView gets updated, then there is a flickering. Without OpenGL it's all fine. But I need OpenGL. Under Win 7 and Ubuntu it's all fine. I'm using QT 4.7 with PyQt 4.8.1. I tried it on a Macbook Pro 2010 with Mac OS X (10.6.4 and 10.6.5) and on a Macbook Air 2009. 
I set the DoubleBuffer to True and tried some other Stuff. It hasn't any effect. 
Hope someone of you can help me to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same problem, I found that it was caused by calling

```
setStyleSheet("QGraphicsView { border-style: none; }");
```

on my QGraphicsView class. Removing this solved the issue. I'm guessing this could be caused by other similar settings.